# How to generate NHibernate query to load entities WHERE Code = 'someCode' OR Code LIKE 'someCode/%', someCode iterated through an IList<string>?

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I have an `IList<string>` named codes storing the code values for which I want to perform a query to retrieve entities from the database.

I have to retrieve all entities for which the code meets the SQL WHERE conditions:

```
Code = 'someCode' OR Code LIKE 'someCode/%'
```

where 'someCode' is successively each code in the `IList<string>` codes.

Example condition:

```
Code = 'someCode0' OR Code LIKE 'someCode0/%'
OR Code = 'someCode1' OR Code LIKE 'someCode1/%'
OR Code = 'someCode2' OR Code LIKE 'someCode2/%'
.
.
.
OR Code = 'someCodeN' OR Code LIKE 'someCodeN/%'
```

Where N is codes.Count - 1.

I tried using `CreateSQLQuery` and generated the above string but I got an exception which came from a bug which was fixed in a later version (using NHibernate 1.2.1.4000).

Thanks for answers!

Comment: Could you provide details of which exception/bug fix you're encountering. Do you not think that that detail could be quite helpful?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: exception is named "clazz_" and there is at least a workaround http://www.methodicmadness.com/2009/01/nhibernate-what-is-heck-clazz.html but I would like to know what is the proper way to construct such a query in NHibernate. It doesn't have to be using CreateSQLQuery, an usual criteria query would be preferred since I don't have any experience using CreateSQLQuery. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using HQL you can use something like this:

```
IQuery q = s.CreateQuery("from Person as p where p.Code in (:code)");
q.SetParameterList("code", someCodes);
```

Where someCodes is your `IList<String>`;

[Here are some other good HQL examples](http://ayende.com/blog/4023/nhibernate-queries-examples) to guide you.

Comment: This queries for all the entities that have code in that list, I need for the code to be exactly a string in the list or for the code to begin with a code in the list followed by a / and then any number of characters. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: In the end this worked since there was a small value range for the like string and I included it in the list passed to the `in` condition.